# Iphone 5s black screen

Tags: iphone

I have an Iphone 5s, the screen randomly went black and shut off, it wont turn back on, I cant hard boot it because my home button is broken and it wont turn on through charge. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You should bring it to Best Buy, or version wireless, they can take it and fix it it might take a day or two depending on how bad it is and it will cost money but not a lot, when I broke my phone I brought it to Verizon wireless and they fixed it it was cheap and quick